# Create an UPDATE MySQL query based on already working SELECT one

Tags: php, mysql, random, sql-update, left-join

I would like to create and UPDATE MySQL query based on a SELECT statement that is already working.

So I have the following select statement that joins two tables - `tbl_random` and `tbl_products`  by finding a random record from the second table:

```
    $sql_select =   "SELECT tbl_random.keyword, tbl_random.model_id,
                    tbl_products.make, tbl_products.model

                    FROM tbl_random LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    tbl_products
                    ON tbl_random.model_id = tbl_products.model

                    GROUP BY tbl_random.keyword       
                    ORDER BY RAND()";

    $rs_select =    $db -> Execute($sql_select);
```

This is how `tbl_random` should look like after the update:

```
+---------+------------+---------+---------+--------------+
| keyword | model_id   | make    |  model  |  more_data1  |
+---------+------------+---------+---------+--------------+
| apple1  | 15         | app5    |  15     |  data1       |
| apple2  | 15         | app1    |  15     |  data2       |
| pear    | 205        | pear53  |  205    |  data3       |
| cherry  | 307        | cher74  |  307    |  data4       |
| melon   | 5023       | melo2   |  5023   |  data5       |
+---------+------------+---------+---------+--------------+
```

What UPDATE query should I use in order to the able to update the `make` and `model` fields in `tbl_random`, with some respective random values from `tbl_products`?

Comment: I'm not quite sure the correctness of the SQL. What is the 'tbl_vehicles' and how the tbl_random and tbl_products related.

Comment: hi, thanks for noticing this...query was copied from another one, which I am modifying in order to create the UPDATE statement. I have corrected the code now. Basically, I need to get one random match from `tbl_products` on this criteria - `tbl_random.model_id = tbl_products.model` and then update `tbl_random.make` with whatever value there is in `tbl_products.make`.